# Declare a List of unknown type and assign the value based on the selection

Tags: c#, asp.net, generic-collections

I have different types of lists, and based on the selected list, my grid needs to be populated. These list item classes are defined as follows:

```
public class plist
{
    public DateTime date_modified { get; set; }
    public DateTime date_added { get; set; }
}

public class cList1 :plist
{
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class cList2 : plist
{
    public string typename { get; set; }
    public int typecode { get; set; }
}
```

In my web page, I need to populate the control based on the list selected `clist1` or `clist2`.

```
protected void Page_Load(object s,EventArgs e)
{
    List<cList1> codes = new List<cList1>();
    List<cList2> types = new List<cList2>();

    switch (getGrpSelValue())
    {
        case (int)LookupType.LU1:
            codes = getMyCodes(0, null, null);
            bindMyGrid(cList1, masterGrd);
            break;
        case (int)LookupType.LU2:
            types = getMyTypes(0, null, null);
            bindMyGrid(cList2, masterGrd);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

public void bindMyGrid<T>(List<T> list, GridView gv)
{
    //binds the grid here
}
```

Is there a way to declare one generic list object and then assign code or types to it and call `bindMyGrid` method once?

Comment: Have you tried using an `ArrayList` ?

Comment: `bindMyGrid(cList1, masterGrd);` where `cList1` in here, it does not map with definition of method

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to optimize/get rid of in this code? Is type safety concern (if not HighCore's suggestion to use `List<object>` is ok)? Or you are trying to simply avoid local variable like `BindMyGrid(GetMyTypes(0, null, null), masterGrid);`?

Comment: It isn't that much repeated code...

Comment: I just listed two different lists, but we have around 18 lists and didn't want to declare 18 different lists and call the bindmygrid method 18 times based on the switch case

Answer (score 0):

```
var codes = new List<object>();

if (condition)
    codes.Add(someClass1);
else
    codes.Add(someClass2);
```

you can store any object as an `object` in a `List<object>`.

Anyways, I don't understand the purpose of this. Why don't you just call the generic method with different parameters?

```
if (condition)
    BindMyGrid<Class1>(someListClass1);
else
    BindMyGrid<Class2>(someListClass2);
```

Comment: You might as well be using an `ArrayList`... -1.

Comment: @newstackexchangeInstance I tend to avoid that. It reminds me of java, which is disgusting.

Comment: Right, it's effective as the same thing.